# EJB with spring : transaction issue in JPA flush

Tags: spring, jpa, transactions, eclipselink, ejb-3.0

I have an issue with an injected EntityManager in my MessageDriven Bean that use spring bean as services (the bootstrap is done with the SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.

Here is the code :

```
@MessageDriven(name = "ProcessMDB")
@Interceptors(SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.class)
public class ProcessMDB implements MessageListener {

    @Autowired
    private ProcessService processService;

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        try {
            id = message.getLongProperty("ID");
            processService.process(id);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Handle error.
        }
    }
```

The process service has a DAO where the EntityManager is injected with the annotation @PersistentContext...

The problem is that if a JPA error occurs in the processService, it may occur during the entityManager.flush() call... so the try catch block is gone and the //Handle error stuff is not done.

So I tried to add manually the flush.

```
@MessageDriven(name = "ProcessMDB")
@Interceptors(SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.class)
public class ProcessMDB implements MessageListener {

    @Autowired
    private ProcessService processService;

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        try {
            id = message.getLongProperty("ID");
            processService.process(id);
            em.flush();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Handle error.
        }
    }
```

But it seems that the flush has no effect.

I've try to add the em.flush in the underlying DAO (just after the persist for instance) and it works! The exception is well raised and the catch block is executed. But it doesn't work if I put the em.flush() at the MessageDrivenBean level.

I think that it's transaction manager problem... The entitymanager in spring beans is not in the same tx than the injected entity manager in my ejb.

If I make em.find in the onMessage() method, the fetched object holds old values (the one in the database), not values that are changed in the service method.

I've configured my database as followed :

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="emf" jndi-name="persistence/PUnit" />
```

and my tx manager as followed :

```
<tx:annotation-driven/>

<tx:jta-transaction-manager />
```

What do I wrong?

Can someonee help me?

Thanks

Stéphane

Answer (score 0):

You have injected `EntityManager` in `ProcessMDB`, but the object is being persisted in `ProcessService`.

Now, how can any operation in `ProcessMDB` can affect `ProcessService`, both will have *probably* their own individual `EntityManager`.

Scope of `PersistenceContext` is upto associated `EntityManager`. The object will be in the context of `ProcessService` & not in `ProcessMDB`, therefore calling flush on later will have no effect & this is expected behaviour.

Comment: That makes senses. But as I'm in the same transaction, I would expect that the container give the same "shared" entity manager both in ProcessService and in ProcessMDB. If I make a em.find(id) in the MDB, the returned object has values from DB, not the last values updated in the processService (because no flush has been done)...

Comment: @Stéphane What is the transaction attribute of ProcessService.process()

Comment: The default one : Required.